# Emergent complexity and Turing Completeness

Tags: turing-completeness

Is there some link between the concept of [emergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) and Turing Completeness?  The ideas feel intuitively like they might be linked, but I can find nothing online.

The idea came to me because I was exploring Conway's Game of Life, and it was hard not to suppose a link between these two properties.

**Edit:** In response to Raphael's point, I have a clarification to the question (which I thought was implied, but in hindsight, it really wasn't)

*Must it be the case that systems that exhibit weak emergent complexity are also Turing Complete?*

Comment: The question in itself is very interesting, but I'm not sure how to frame it. Turing completeness is a property of *computational models*, mathematical, "ideal" objects with a formal definition. On the other hand, natural phenomena exist in the real world, and we can at most *model* them with our mathematical tools. Whether or not a model is suitable for a given phenomenon depends on what kind of questions you want to ask to the model, and there are often multiple valid models,  used depending on context.

Comment: Conway's Game of Life is just a special case of a cellular automaton, a computational model that in some variants is indeed universal.

Comment: This seems like a prompt for philosophical discussion, not a question for scientific or mathematical facts. Too broad? Primarily opinion-based? Community votes, please!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you  to give  a look to S. Wolfram's book "A New Kind Of Science" (that is also available [online](http://www.wolframscience.com/nks/)).

The centeral ideas are:

- Computation is everywhere
- Almost all processes that are not obviously simple can be viewed as computations of equivalent sophistication ([Principle of Computational Equivalence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofComputationalEquivalence.html))
- [Computation irreducibility](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComputationalIrreducibility.html): while many computations admit shortcuts that allow them to be performed more rapidly, others cannot be sped up.

Though these ideas are probably not new, they are exposed in a fascinating way (to be honest, a rather informal and non-mathematical "way").